# Hadoop: How to output different format types in the same job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, gzip, lzo

I want to output `gzip` and `lzo` formats at the same time in one job.

I used `MultipleOutputs`, and add two named outputs like this:

`MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "LzoOutput", GBKTextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);`

`GBKTextOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, LzoCodec.class);`

`MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "GzOutput", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);`

`TextOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, GzipCodec.class);`

(`GBKTextOutputFormat` here is written by myself which extends `FileOutputFormat`)

They are used in reducer like:

`multipleOutputs.write("LzoOutput", NullWritable.get(), value, "/user/hadoop/lzo/"+key.toString());`

`multipleOutputs.write("GzOutput", NullWritable.get(), value, "/user/hadoop/gzip/"+key.toString());`

The result is:

I can get outputs in the two path, but they are both in `gzip` format.

Someone can help me? Thanks!

==========================================================================

More:

I just looked at the source code of `setOutputCompressorClass` in `FileOutputFormat`, in which `conf.setClass("mapred.output.compression.codec", codecClass, CompressionCodec.class);`

It seems that mapred.output.compression.codec in configuration will be reset when setOutputCompressorClass is called.

So the actual compression format is the one we set at last, and we cannot set two different compression formats in the same job ? Or there is something else ignored ?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your GBKTextOutputFormat works when used as the only output format type in a reducer that isn't running MultipleOutput?  Also that in your custom output format class the compression class is set to something other than GzipCodec in the getRecordWriter() method?

Comment: I meant the default compression class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So maybe as a work-around, try setting the correct outputCompressorClass directly in the configuration

```
context.getConfiguration().setOutputCompressorClass(GzipCodec.class);
```

just before your write call to each of the outputs.  It does look like any output format configuration parameters other than key class, value class and output path are not handled well by MultipleOutputs and we may have to write a bit of code to offset that oversight.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! GBKTextOutputFormat actually works well when there is only one output format type. I will try to setOutputCompressorClass before each `multipleOutputs.write(...)`.

Comment: I'm looking forward to hearing how it goes.  The MultipleOutputs object you instantiate actually caches a RecordWriter for each output and that RecordWriter is constructed the first time you try to write something to the output.  The problem as we've discussed is that different outputs step on each other's configuration settings and then the RecordWriters are not created correctly.  In theory :)

Comment: The RecordWriter is cached in MultipleOutputs object exactly as your point. The context of RecordWriter is obtained by taskContext = getContext(...);, which directly return taskContext if not equal to null. That makes our setOutputCompressorClass before MultipleOutputs.write do not work. So I copy MultipleOutputs as another class and modify the getContext() function. It will not return if taskContext != null. Everything seems OK now, and what I should do next is to ensure taskContext to be instantiated only once for each nameOutput, or it will run too slowly. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I hadn't thought of creating a new MultipleOutputs-like class.  Very cool.

Comment: @thomaslee: see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981233/hadoop-multipleoutputs-does-not-write-to-multiple-files-when-file-formats-are-cu

Comment: Nice! That helps me output to different directories that unknown in advance. Thank you!@Chris