# Hadoop: How to output different format types in the same job? (part II)

Tags: hadoop

I would like to write compressed and uncrompressed files within the same reducer using MultipleOutputs, but it seems to be an all or nothing. If I do:

```
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "ToGzip", TextOutputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, Text.class);
    TextOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
    TextOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, GzipCodec.class);
```

It will compress everything, not only the files that I want. If you look at this very similar question:

[Hadoop: How to output different format types in the same job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953010/hadoop-how-to-output-different-format-types-in-the-same-job)

You will see that it will fix my problem, but it uses the old interface and the new one does not have:

```
context.getConfiguration().setOutputCompressorClass(GzipCodec.class);
```

What would be the equivalent solution with the new Hadoop API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is, I don't think you can right now.

Longer answer/rant. Multiple outputs in Hadoop are a mess. Add in HBase and it gets *really* messy. The multiple output "feature" that exists today seem more like a fragile hack that is "good enough". Since options are usually job scoped, there is little granular control over individual outputs.

If you *need* output specific compression then your best bet is to create your own OutputFormat by extending an existing one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I went ahead and trivially extended TextOutputFormat to compress the output. I am accepting your answer because of your good advice.